# Delete first word from string on C

Tags: c, string, words

I have a function that receive two char array (resource and result) and change them. the result will be only the first word and resource for everything that it was before, except the first word. The first word is written to the result, but in the resource removes some spaces...

```
void selectFirstWord(char *src, char* res) {
int i = 1;

while(*src != ' ' && *src != 0) {
   *(res++) = *(src++); //посимвольное копирование из src в res
   i++;
}

while(*src != 0) {
    *(src++) = *(src+i);
}

*res = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please write this in English ...

Comment: Or post on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @RingØ I did it.

Comment: `*(src++) = *(src+i);` There is no sequence point here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a copy of the original `src`

```
void selectFirstWord(char *src, char* res) {

    char *copy = src;                  // keep copy

    while(*src != ' ' && *src != 0) {
        *res++ = *src++;
    }
    *res = 0; // "close" res

    while(*src == ' ') src++; // eat spaces after the word

    // Copy the rest of src to `copy`
    do {
        *copy++ = *src;   
    } while(*src++ != 0);
}
```

Differences with your code

- `copy` keeps copy of `src`
- after `res` gets first word of `src`, eat following spaces in `src`
- then copy the remaining part of `src` to `copy` (which points to the original `src`)

There is also a solution using indexes. `src[i]`, but here we just follow `src` being incremented from start to bottom.